Feign error decoder error :Request processing failed; nested exception
I want to create an error handler for my Feign client, so I created a CustomErrorDecoder, updated the Feign configuration to use this new error decoder, created custom exceptions, and finally threw the exception. However, when the exception is thrown, I get this error, and I don't know what the problem is. This is the error message:

Request processing failed; nested exception is
fr.application.configuration.exceptions.NotFoundException: Error
occurred. error.already_closed_or_unknown     at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]  at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]

this is the error decoder :
public class CustomErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {
    private final ErrorDecoder defaultErrorDecoder = new Default();

    @Override
    public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
        ErrorMessage message;
        try (InputStream bodyIs = response.body()
                .asInputStream()) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            message = mapper.readValue(bodyIs, ErrorMessage.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
        return switch (response.status()) {
            case 400 -> new BadRequestException(message.getMessage() != null ? message.getMessage() : "Bad Request");
            case 404 -> new NotFoundException(message.getErrorCode() != null ? message.getErrorCode() : "Not found");
            default -> defaultErrorDecoder.decode(methodKey, response);
        };
    }
}

the configuration of feign :
    private static <T> T createClient(Class<T> clientClass, String baseUrl) {
        BUSINESS_LOGGER.info("Creating client for class {} with base URL {}", clientClass, baseUrl);
        return Feign.builder()
                .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
                .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
                .errorDecoder(new CustomErrorDecoder())
                .logger(new Slf4jLogger(clientClass))
                .logLevel(feign.Logger.Level.FULL)
                .target(clientClass, baseUrl);
    }

and this is how i throw the exception
        try {
            return apiClient.endPoint(Url,
                    body);
        } catch (NotFoundException | BadRequestException | InternalServerErrorException e) {
            BUSINESS_LOGGER.error( e.getMessage());
            throw e;  
        }

and the endPint of my feign client
    @RequestLine("POST {endpoint}")
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type: application/json",
    })
    ObjectDto endPoint( @Param("endpoint") String endpoint, ObjectDto object);


I discovered that handling Feign client errors can be done with just an exception handler like this one, without the need to configure an ErrorDecoder
    @ExceptionHandler(FeignException.class)
    public ErrorMessage handleFeignException(FeignException feignException, WebRequest webRequest){
        String requestPath = ((ServletWebRequest) webRequest).getRequest().getRequestURI();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        int statusCode = feignException.status();
            String content = feignException.contentUTF8();

            if (content != null && content.trim().startsWith("{")) {
                JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(content);

                if(Objects.nonNull(jsonNode.get("error_code"))) {
                    String errorMessage = jsonNode.get("error_code").toString();
                    return new ErrorMessage(errorMessage, statusCode, requestPath);
                }
                if(Objects.nonNull(jsonNode.get("message"))) {
                    String errorMessage = jsonNode.get("message").toString();
                    return new ErrorMessage(errorMessage, statusCode, requestPath);
                }
            } else {
                return new ErrorMessage("Invalid response format, not JSON", HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED.value(), requestPath);
            }

        return new ErrorMessage("Unknown error occurred", HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED.value(), requestPath);
    }

created a ErrorMessage pojo with errorCode errorMessage and path and that's all
